# Fluent NHibernate Optimistic Lock and Lazy Load

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I am new to fluent nhibernate (and also hibernate). I generated my nhibernate code using LLBLGEN. Now, from what I see in tutorials, the code that LLBLGEN generates is not very good so I am a bit suspicios and decided to examine the output.

Every mapping file has the following lines in their constructor called before mapping the properties to columns:

```
Table("TABLE_NAME");
OptimisticLock.None();
LazyLoad();
```

I understand the `Table` method but what about the others ? Are they really necessary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take my answer as a deduction from the existing literature on the Internet, since I'm no expert on NHibernate.

### First, the `LazyLoad();` sentence.

No matter how you are defined default lazy loading strategy on your project, the `LazyLoad();` sentence [forces](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/ClassMap.cs#L347) NHibernate to implement lazy loading when mappings are performed.

### Second, the `OptimisticLock.None();` sentence.

From Ayende's related post to the [NHibernate mapping concurrence](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency):

> None basically means that we fall back to the transaction semantics
>   that we use in the database. The database may throw us out, but aside
>   from that, we don’t really care much about things.

And reviewing the [Hibernate project documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

> If you enable dynamic-update, you will have a choice of optimistic locking strategies:
>
> - version: check the version/timestamp columns
> - all: check all columns
> - dirty: check the changed columns, allowing some concurrent updates
> - none: do not use optimistic locking

I assume that the use of `OptimisticLock.None();` sentence on the code tells NHibernate that does not establish any locking strategy and defers locking behavior to the underlying database.